# Solving systems of equations modulo a certain number, with or without numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, equation, modulo

Suppose I have this system of equations:

[image]

If I wanted to solve it using numpy, I would simply do this:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 1, 1],[1,3,9],[1,5,8]])
b = numpy.array([8, 10, 11])

print(numpy.linalg.solve(a,b))
```

Which would print this as a result:

```
[7.33333333 0.55555556 0.11111111]
```

What if the system of equations was modulo a number `n` however? I have checked the numpy documentation and it looks like systems of equations in modulo is not supported out of the box by the library.

For example, in modulo 17, the results of this system of equations would be 13, 10 and 2:

[image]

Is there any way I can solve this system of equations in Python? Either with some numpy functions that I might have missed, or by manually writing some helper function?

Comment: What do you mean by "modulo something"?

Comment: @Anwarvic Modulo a number. I will edit the question to make it clearer. For example, the first equation would be `a0 + a1 + a2 mod 17 = 8`. Or in other words, solving the system of equations over the set $Z_17$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `gcd(a.det(), m) == 1` you can do following. The idea is to use `adj(a) = det(a) * a^(-1)` so keeping all parts as integer.

```
import sympy
from math import gcd

a = sympy.Matrix([[1, 1, 1],[1,3,9],[1,5,8]])
b = sympy.Matrix([8, 10, 11])
m = 17

det = int(a.det())
if gcd(det, m) == 1:
    ans = pow(det, -1, m) * a.adjugate() @ b % m
    print(ans)
else:
    print("don't know")
# Matrix([[13], [10], [2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/), or, if you are adventurous, in [`glank`](https://github.com/Glank/Galois). There is also a pure python implementation [here](http://www.math.umbc.edu/%7Ecampbell/Computers/Python/numbthy.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. `glank` looked interesting (I am adventurous) but unfortunately it's built for Python 2. Before looking into `sage`, I would be willing to give a try to the pure Python implementation, but it's not clear to me how I would combine that finite field class with a system of equations in numpy. Would you mind sharing some code?