# Solve a linear matrix equation with modulo 2

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, modulo

I have a matrix like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [1,1,1,0],
    [1,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,1],
    [0,1,1,1]
])
```

and a vector:

```
b = np.array([0,1,1,1])
```

and I want to solve the equation: *A * x = b*. But I want to solve it in modulo 2. That means *1 + 1 = 0*. So the solution in this case would be:

```
x = np.array([0,0,0,1])
```

I found [Solving systems of equations modulo a certain number, with or without numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599169/solving-systems-of-equations-modulo-a-certain-number-with-or-without-numpy), but the solution doesn't work for me, for some reason. I get the error:

> ValueError: pow() 2nd argument cannot be negative when 3rd argument specified

Why is it not working? Is there another solution?

Comment: Have you tried either avoiding to provide the 3rd argument to `pow`, or avoiding negative 2nd arguments if the 3rd argument is provided?

Comment: How would you solve this with pen & paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the modulus, you cannot use classic *linear algebra* methods to solve this *combinatorial* problem. Hopefully, the use of modulus 2 make the problem much simpler. Indeed, addition modulus 2 behave like the XOR binary function and multiplication like the AND binary function. As a result the problem can be rewritten as the following:

```
x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 ^  0 = 0
x1 ^ x2 ^  0 ^ x4 = 1
x1 ^  0 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 1
 0 ^ x2 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 1
```

Thus:

```
x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 = 0
x1 ^ x2 ^ x4 = 1
x1 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 1
x2 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 1
```

This example can be trivially solved because `x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 = 0` means either that x1, x2 and x3 are zero or that two of the tree variable are set to one, which conflict with the 3 following rules.

However, on any arbitrary `A` matrix, the problem seems hard to solve and is very close to solving a [boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), which is proven to be [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).

Moreover, note that the solution may not exist or may not be unique regarding `A` and `b`.

Using a **CSP solver** will definitively help to solve this problem easily while it may not be an optimal way if the problem is not NP-complete (this has yet to be proven). There are many Python library that can solve this (OR-tools for example should be able to do that).

Comment: Thank you for you response. The way the program is set up I will always work on solvable problems. I can't tell if it's NP-complete (never quite understood this). I want to use it on 9x9 / 25x25 Matrices. 

Any chance you could give me a quick example how to implement a CSP solver for such a problem? I never worked with this before. No problem if you can't. And thanks again for you help.

Comment: Btw. the 9x9 matrix is always:
A = np.array([
        [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]
    ])
(sorry about the format. I'm not used to stackoverflow yet)

Comment: I did not used a CSP-solver since several years so I am not very familiar with their API. The last time I use OR-tools to do such kind of thing it was great. I think it can easily solve your 9x9 problem. I am not such for the 25x25, but the heuristics of OR-tools are quite good, so it may be fine. You can read the [documentation example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) to start with. Note that you can hardcode the constraints since the matrix is known statically (do not include the zeros, use the xor operators and boolean variables).