# How to use AddBoolXOr in OR-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I try to understand OR-tools. I want to solve this equations system in modulo 2:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + 0  = 0
x1 + x2 + 0  + x4 = 1
x1 + 0  + x3 + x4 = 1
0  + x2 + x3 + x4 = 1
```

this equates because of the modulo 2 to:

```
x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 = 0
x1 ^ x2 ^ x4 = 1
x1 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 1
x2 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 1
```

using the bitwise xor (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019736/solve-a-linear-matrix-equation-with-modulo-2/68026977?noredirect=1#comment120261920_68026977)).

So I tried the following code:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Creates the model.
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Creates the variables.
x1 = model.NewBoolVar('x1')
x2 = model.NewBoolVar('x2')
x3 = model.NewBoolVar('x3')
x4 = model.NewBoolVar('x4')

# Creates the constraints.
model.AddBoolXOr(x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 == 0)
model.AddBoolXOr(x1 ^ x2 ^ x4 == 1)
model.AddBoolXOr(x1 ^ x3 ^ x4 == 1)
model.AddBoolXOr(x2 ^ x3 ^ x4 == 1)

# Creates a solver and solves the model.
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    print('x1 = %i' % solver.Value(x1))
    print('x2 = %i' % solver.Value(x2))
    print('x3 = %i' % solver.Value(x3))
    print('x4 = %i' % solver.Value(x4))
```

but I get:

> 'calling xor on a linear expression is not supported, '
> NotImplementedError: calling xor on a linear expression is not supported,  please use CpModel.AddBoolXor

If I use `AddBoolXor` instead of `AddBoolXOr` I get:

> AttributeError: 'CpModel' object has no attribute 'AddBoolXor'

Comment: Have you checked the documentation already? Just for starters, https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html suggests that the argument of `AddBoolXOr()` is a list of literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddBoolXor` takes an array of Boolean literals.

```
model.AddBoolXOr([x1, x2.Not(), x3])
```

The semantic of `AddBoolXor(xi)` is `sum(xi) % 2 == 1`

So, in your case

```
# Creates the constraints.
model.AddBoolXOr([x1, x2, x3, True])
model.AddBoolXOr([x1, x2, x4])
model.AddBoolXOr([x1, x3, x4])
model.AddBoolXOr([x2, x3, x4])
```